# Input.checked creates Dynamic element that needs to be bound to input

Tags: javascript, html

I have a filter and I'm dynamically creating `li` elements when the input is checked, but the issue is I can't seem to clear the input when you click on the element. So I'm looking to bind the input and the dynamic together. Thank you for help in advance.

HTML:

```
<ul class="options flavorProfiles">
    <li class="fl"><input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="ftSweet" value="Sweet" />
        <label for="ftSweet">Sweet</label></li>
    <li class="fl"><input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="ftSavory" value="Savory" />
        <label for="ftSavory">Savory</label></li>
    <li class="fl"><input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="ftSpicy" value="Spicy" />
        <label for="ftSpicy">Spicy</label></li>
    <li class="fl"><input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="ftTangy" value="Tangy" />
        <label for="ftTangy">Tangy</label></li>
</ul>
<div class="results-label">Filters Applied:
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="filterClear">Remove All</a>
</div>
<ul id="results"></ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $li;
    // Adds 'expand' to .cat-filter on click
    $('.filter-header').click(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass("expand")) {
            $(this).removeClass("expand");
        } 
        else {
            $(this).addClass("expand");
        }
    });

    // Turns Filter Groups On/Off
    $('.filter-header.secPB').click(function() {
        $('.options.prodBenefits').toggle();
    });
    $('.filter-header.secSD').click(function() {
        $('ul.options.specialDiets').toggle();
    });
    $('.filter-header.secFP').click(function() {
        $('ul.options.flavorProfiles').toggle();
    });

    // Adds/Removes input value text under results
                            $('.options input').change(function() {
                                if (this.checked) {
                                    $li = $('<li class="active-filter"></li>');
                                    $li.text(this.value);
                                    $('#results').append($li);


                                    var input = this; 
                                    $li.click(function () {
                                        $(input).click();


                                    });
                                }   
                                else {
                                    $('li:contains('+this.value+')', '#results').remove();

                                }
                            });


                            // Clears ALL filter results on click
                            $('#filterClear').click(function() {
                                $('#results').empty($li);
                            });


                        }); // DOM Ready
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want, and where the problem is. Your JavaScript code also references stuff that is not in the HTML you provided.

Comment: The problem is when I click on the li created '$li' i want it to clear the input:checked only and not all inputs that have been :checked. Right now when i click on the $li it removes it but doesn't uncheck the input used to created it. Help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
$($li).on("click", this, clear(this.value));
```

It intends to bind a function as event handler to the newly inserted `li` element, but instead you actually call `clear` right there. This effectively means you are not binding an event handler. One solution could be to use `clear.bind(null, this.value)` for that argument.

Also, the second argument is strange: you pass a DOM element (`this`), but jQuery will interpret that as being data to be passed as `event.data`. It cannot interpret it as a selector (if that was the intention), because that would have to be a string.

Thirdly, you are making a jQuery object of something that already is a jQuery object. So write `$li` instead of `$($li)`.

Depending on what you wanted to do there, you can probably use this syntax:

```
$li.click(clear.bind(null, this.value));
```

But as you actually want to mimic un-checking the corresponding checkbox (input), it is easier to just trigger a click on it. So use this instead:

```
var input = this; // reference to `this` will be lost, so save it
$li.click(function () {
    $(input).click() // Trigger a click event on the checkbox
});
```

So now clicking the `li` element will also trigger a click on the checkbox, and execute the event handler you have on it. The `else` part in that handler will then be executed.

Comment: This worked for cleaning the dynamically created li but i still need to uncheck the input that was used to create the li.

Comment: See addition to my answer.

Comment: So i thought that worked but it is still not clearing the filter. It does uncheck the box but it doesn't look like the else is being fired to clear the filter.

I replaced the $li.click(clear... with var input = this;.... sections from above. Thoughts?

Comment: I've updated the code sample. It looks like the '$(input).click() goes to the 'else' but it doesn't clear like it does when you manually click the input.

Comment: Could you provide the definition of the function `clear` in your question? Please also put back your original code in your question, otherwise my answer does not make sense anymore. You can always add to your question some other code, but don't remove the *essential* parts of your original question.

Comment: Nevermind. This is working afterall. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Good to hear. Good luck!